# just started learning python and getting syntax error no else statement

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and trying a simple example but getting a syntax error on my else statement.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 10
>>> if a > b:
...     print(" a is greater")
...     else:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help me understand this error.

Comment: your `else` is indented to far. it should be inline with your `if`. However i would also suggest reading the stackoverflow guide on how to ask a question

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your else statment is indented to far. Python defines code blocks by indentation. Youe else statement should be inline with your if statment.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 10
>>> if a > b:
...     print(" a is greater")
... else:
...     print(" b is greater")
...
 b is greater
```

Comment: Good answer @Chris Doyle, just a small irrelevant suggested typo, "Youe" should be "You're"